# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{i}b_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{j}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> **Proposition** $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{i}b_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{j}$$

My attempt:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{i}b_{j} = \bigr(a_{1}b_{1} + a_{1}b_{2} + \cdots + a_{1}b_{m}\bigl) + \bigr(a_{2}b_{1} + a_{2}b_{2} + \cdots + a_{2}b_{m}\bigl) + \cdots + \bigr(a_{n}b_{1} + a_{n}b_{2} + \cdots + a_{n}b_{m}\bigl) = $$

$$ = \bigr(a_1b_{1} + a_2b_{1} \cdots a_nb_{1}\bigr) + \bigr(a_1b_{2} + a_2b_{2} \cdots a_nb_{2}\bigr) + \cdots + \bigr(a_1b_{m} + a_2b_{m} \cdots a_nb_{m}\bigr) = \sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{j}$$

Is it correct?

---

There is a lot of $\cdots$ notation involved, hence I suspect that there might be something wrong.

Comment: An ellipsis is usually indicative of an induction argument that's being suppressed. In this case, double induction is warranted, both on $n$ and on $m$. I would personally not like to write that up myself, and would instead simply say "The result follows from the commutativity of addition", and forego even the argument you've written.

Comment: Another more reasonable approach, given the summand, might be to prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_i b_j = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=1}^m b_j\right)$$ and then commute the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is correct but does not really explain why it is true.  Let $C$ be the $n$ by $m$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $c_{i,j} = a_i b_j$.  Both double sums add up all the entries in $C$.  The left-hand side adds up the entries in each row and then adds up these row sums.  The right-hand side adds up the entries in each column and then adds up these column sums.

Alternatively:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_i b_j &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{j=1}^m b_j \\ &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^m b_j\right) \\ &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^m b_j\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right) \\&= \sum_{j=1}^m b_j \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \\&= \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n b_j a_i \\&= \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_j
\end{align}